# Can the PHP send the Data URI of a file to the database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, backend

I am trying to build an application via PHP. This is my first step in the back-end developing. In this application, I need to upload files to database, but as DataURI not as the normal way. any help?? This is what I tried to do :

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>PHP FileUploader</title></head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
<!-- The Visible form : -->
<table>
    <tr><td>The name of file :</td><td><input type="text" id="FileNameInput" placeholder="Enter your File Name.."/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>The description of file :</td><td><textarea id="FileDescInput" placeholder="Enter your File Description.."</textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>The file :</td><td><input type="file" id="FileInput"/></td></tr>
</table>

<!-- The invisible Form : -->
<div style="display:none;">
<input id="FileNameSubmit" name="FileName" />
<textarea id="FileDescSubmit" name="FileDesc" />
<textarea id="FileSubmit" name="File"> </textarea>
</div>

<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit new Data</button>

<script>
var fileReader
document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = ()=>{
    document.getElementById('FileNameSubmit').value = document.getElementById('FileNameInput').value
    document.getElementById('FileDescSubmit').value = document.getElementById('FileDescInput').value

document.getElementById('FileInput').onchange = ()=>{
fileReader = new FileReader()
fileReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('FileInput').files[0])
fileReader.onload = ()=>{
document.getElementById('FileSubmit').value = fileReader.result
}
}

<?php
$username = "root" ;
$password = "" ;
$database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=files;charset=utf8;",$username,$password) ;
if($database){echo "<script>console.log('connected successfully to database !')</script>";}

$command = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO file(name,description,file) VALUES(:name, :desc, :file);") ;

$command->bindParam("name" , $_POST("FileName"));
$command->bindParam("desc" , $_POST("FileDesc"));
$command->bindParam("file" , $_POST("File"));

$command->execute() ;
?>
}
</script>

</form>

</body>
```

but this piece of code is not working. 
**NOTE :** the table in the example above only for decoration 
any help ????
Thanks from now.

Comment: Look into the `$_FILES` global variable in PHP, as well as `move_uploaded_file`. These are 2 of the core parts used in file uploads. You will most likely need to setup a dedicated folder on the server to save these files. You *can* store files as binary data in the database but it's not ideal (in most cases), instead you store a reference to that file (its location or id so that you know what to load).

Comment: _"any help??"_ - with what, specifically? You have not even given us an actual problem description here. And why would you need to make these uploads as a data URI in the first place?

Comment: It is not a good idea to store Data Uri in the database. Especially given it's your first steps. Store images in the filesystem

Comment: Agreed, I'm struggling to see any reason to mess about with a FileReader and data URIs here. Just upload the file in the standard way.

Comment: Thank you all. I need to use the FileReader in Javascript because it is easy to me to do that so, I don't want to make the files in the server because I don't need to delete only the thing exist on database (the files paths) I need to delete the files forever, but I will try the standard way. Thank you all

Comment: `I need to use the FileReader in Javascript because it is easy`...that doesn't make any sense. All your JavaScript code is doing is taking the file selected by the user in a `type="file"` input field, and getting a data URI from it. You don't need to do that just to upload it. You can submit the form and the file data will be uploaded directly with it, without needing any JavaScript. You just need a couple of small changes to your form. Here's the PHP documentation's explanation of what to do: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php